# Generating asp controls with mark up in db

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am storing some string s in database. After reading it I am trying to generate a button as follows:

```
String s = "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button";
Type T = Type.GetType(s,true);
```

But I am getting following exception:

```
Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' from assembly 'WebApplication2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

How can I generate asp.button using database if I store the whole markup for button as follows in db:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Button" />
```

I am able to render HTML controls using asp.Literal. But is it possible to generate asp controls in similar manner or the above approach of generating Type object I am trying?

Comment: you can use placeholders to add dynamic controls on runtime

Comment: @JohnSaunders I had to ask it some other way since no one answered it there...

Comment: Don't do that here. If nobody answers it, then improve the question, don't ask the same bad question again.

Comment: I was trying something different this time, I did put code there and here yet nobody replied properly...I really have to solve this hence asked here whatever I thought...